# typescript error cannot find module 'firebase/app'

Tags: angular, angularfire

I am trying to integrate ngx-admin with firebase. i have install firebase in my angular project.but it gives me such error "typescript error cannot find module 'firebase/app'." i have try to install typing also but doesn't got any luck

my stackstrace

```
D:\admin-ionic> ng serve
Your global Angular CLI version (1.6.1) is greater than your local
version (1.4.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2017-12-21T08:36:34.546Z
Hash: ecdd99ad138ea0774dff
Time: 8026ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 1.06 kB {vendor} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 323 bytes {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 694 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 338 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts (1,27): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts (3,27): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts (1,27): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts (1,27): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/firestore.d.ts (1,27): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts (1,27): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts (2,27): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.d.ts (1,27): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/database/interfaces.d.ts (1,27): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.d.ts (1,26): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/database/list/state-changes.d.ts (3,26): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/database/list/audit-trail.d.ts (3,26): Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module D:/admin-society/node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/admin-society/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/admin-society/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/admin-society/src/app/app.module.ts
    at syntaxError (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:212:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (D:\admin-society\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:448:24)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Here is my code

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase : {
    apiKey: '***************************************',
    authDomain: 'ionicadmin-123456.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://ionicadmin-123456.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'ionicadmin-123456',
    storageBucket: 'ionicadmin-123456.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '123456789123',
  },
};
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule, // imports firebase/firestore, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
  ],
})
```

committee.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-chartjs',
  styleUrls: ['./committee.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './committee.component.html',
})
export class CommitteeComponent {
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

committee.component.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 27):

It seems that firebase 4.8.1 has changed its typescript typings.

For now you can revert back to firebase 4.8.0 by running the following:

```
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase@4.8.0
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: Working on React as well

Answer (score 14):

After Angular4+ this works differently. Below are the steps to use firebase into angular project:

```
$ npm install --save firebase @angular/fire -f
```

Next, you can create and export a constant for configuration of firebase, or open the environments/environment.ts file in your Angular project and add the firebaseConfig object inside the environment object. 
*I prefer the second solution because can change depending on environment*:

> export const environment = {   production: false,   firebaseAppConfig:
>   {...}

Import all needed modules into you custom module like this:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
        // [...]
    imports: [
        // [...]
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule
    ],
```

Ether way if you want more details to create an angular project with firebase, follow the instruction in this link:
[Angular Firestore Tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-firestore-tutorial/)

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same problem but i solved it after running npm install firebase in the directory where my package.json is available.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was just to add `compat` to my imports.

Instead of

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

I wrote:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
```

Answer (score 0):

environment code like this

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase : {
    apiKey: '***************************************',
    authDomain: 'ionicadmin-123456.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://ionicadmin-123456.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'ionicadmin-123456',
    storageBucket: 'ionicadmin-123456.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '123456789123',
  }
};
```